# excel =SIN(MOD($B5;23)/23*2*PI()) error

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have written instruction from my college professor to type this formula:

```
=SIN(MOD($B5;23)/23*2*PI()),
```

but when I do it, Excel won't accept it, because the formula contains an error.

Am I doing something wrong or is it possible that professor gave us bad instructions?

Answer (score 2):

If the formula contains `,` character too, then that's why. Otherwise the formula works for me in a blank Excel, which means that the error may be somewhere in `$B5` if it's not the `,` character.

functions:

- `sin()`
- `mod()`
- `pi()`

and parenthesis seems ok + the rest is just numbers. (Excel 2010)

```
=SIN(MOD($B5;23)/23*2*PI())
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your professor made a typo on the instructions. Try 
`=SIN(MOD($B5,23)/23*2*PI())`

I'm not on a computer with Excel so I'm unable to test it. However, the [documentation](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-mod-function) for the MOD function in excel uses a comma instead of a semicolon.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, professor made a typo, it's working when I put comma instead of the semicolon.

Comment: You should comment the answer, instead of adding an answer.

Comment: You should also probably accept TemperedFate's answer, since they correctly advised you what the problem was.  It is quite possible that this was not a "typo", per se, but might have been a formula from an international version of Excel.  It is common for commas in U.S. versions of Excel to be represented by semicolons in other countries' versions.